# Academic project on Android

Tags: android, project

I need an idea for an academic project that I need to submit to my college. I'm looking for an academic project in mobile computing domain(android) which has an IEEE base paper(preferably). I really don't know if its the right question to ask here. But I really don't understand where to look. I don't need the implementation or anything. I just need the IEEE base paper and the details of the project and I will try and implement it. I searched fruitlessly through the IEEE website, please help. Please note that I have just started learning J2ME so i am a beginner. I would preferably like IEEE based project, if not possible like that, atleast give me some good project please. I have been desperately searching for this for 2 long days. Please help.

Comment: That's nice. However, SO is not the place to ask. See the FAQ for acceptable questions. (I would choose something *fun and creative*, but hey, that's just me.)

Comment: I also figured SO is not a place to ask such a thing. But i can't really figure out where else to ask. I just need a solution, no matter where it comes from. Any ideas where this might work??

Comment: I was considering flagging it as well. However `programmers` doesn't seem to be right either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IEEE standards are usually hardware standards. I'm not sure if you will be able to find a standard that is implementation only. Have a look at their [published standards](http://standards.ieee.org/cgi-bin/lp_index?status=all&pg=40&type=standard&coll=2&offset=0). These are on computer technology. Maybe you should have a look at the [other areas](http://standards.ieee.org/findstds/index.html).

Comment: Most of what the IEEE publishes isn't standards. The IEEE Computer Society, for instance, publishes a huge number of computer-related papers. There are also plenty of papers on mobile computing published by other parts of IEEE, dealing with things like antenna design, spectrum management, etc.

Comment: If not IEEE any ideas on good projects(academic) on android are also welcome. Please help.

Comment: I would put areas like "antenna design", "spectrum management" in the hardware area. You are designing some hardware and develop a driver for it. I think that won't work out for the OP as it's already implemented on his phone.

Comment: let alone IEEE, any ideas on `good` android projects??